# Joomla 2.5 mod_login Is not working

Tags: joomla2.5

actually i inserted the "login through facebook button" in mod_login after that when I enter the username and password, the pages simple get refresh and nothing happens..
I have checkd the code many times but all in vain is there an technical problem.?
keeping in mind i am using JoMsocial in my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, delete your browser cache and try, if not then go to global configuration and clean the cookie domain field and still have the same trouble then download through ftp index.php from home folder where joomla is installed and open with notepad then press save as from menu and save it with ANSI type and upload it, this may help. Give us url of your site